# script for all files

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that calculates which file is bigger. Here I show what I have

```
p1="$HOME"
p2="backup.tar.gz"
p3="curl"

size1=`du $p1/$p2 | awk '{print $1}'`
size2=`du $p1/$p3 | awk '{print $1}'`

if [ $size1-gt $size2]
then
    echo "high is $p2"
else
    echo "high is $p3"
fi
```

I want to determine which are the largest files or directories of $HOME when it can have many and not only two

Comment: @Sergio Yes, I want to determine which are the largest files or directories of $HOME when it can have many and not only two (as I have it now)

Comment: You could use `find(1)`. To get the 10 largest files in HOME:  `find $HOME -type f -exec ls -lh {} + | sort -hr -k5 | tail -n10 | awk '{ print $5" "$9 }'`

Comment: But... do you want a script or you can use tools which can already give you the answer? find(1) and du(1) piped to sort(1) can already do that.

Comment: @Sergio This shows me the smaller ones, that is, their size is 0

Answer (score 0):

Your problem reduces to

```
du "$HOME"/* | sort -n
```

Like most sane tools, `du` accepts a *list* of file name arguments; and repeated pairwise comparisons are extremely wasteful when you can simply sort. A good sorting algorithm eliminates most pairwise comparisons - it knows that if A is bigger than B and B is bigger than C, A must be bigger than C, too.